# jquery doesn't work in page called by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I have the following in a page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    alert('moo');
                });
```

It will show the alert when I view that page BUT if that page is called via Ajax then the alert will not show... Any ideas why? Or how to get around this?

Note: This is test javascript and i'm not actually showing an alert in my real app

Thanks

Ajax jazz as requested:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('ul#ui-ajax-tabs li a').click(function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("ul#ui-ajax-tabs li").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).parents('li').addClass("loading");
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            var link = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (responseHtml)
                {
                    //$('div#ui-tab-content').html($(responseHtml));
                    $('div#ui-tab-content').html($(responseHtml).find('div#ui-tab-content > div#ui-ajax-html'));
                    $(link).parents('li').addClass('selected');
                    $("ul#ui-ajax-tabs li").removeClass("loading");
                    History.pushState(null, $(responseHtml).filter('title').text(), url)
                },
                error: function (responseHtml)
                {
                    $('div#ui-tab-content').html('<div class="message error"><p><strong>Something went wrong...</strong> Please contact the Administrator!</p></div>');
                    $(link).parents('li').addClass('selected');
                    $("ul#ui-ajax-tabs li").removeClass("loading");
                    History.pushState(null, $(responseHtml).filter('title').text(), url)
                },
                statusCode:
                {
                    404: function (responseHtml)
                    {
                        $('div#ui-tab-content').html('<div class="message error"><p><strong>Error 404 (Not Found)</strong> Please contact the Administrator!</p></div>');
                        $(link).parents('li').addClass('selected');
                        $("ul#ui-ajax-tabs li").removeClass("loading");
                        History.pushState(null, 'Error 404 (Not Found)', url)
                    },
                    500: function (responseHtml)
                    {
                        $('div#ui-tab-content').html('<div class="message error"><p><strong>Error 500 (Internal Server Error)</strong> Please contact the Administrator!</p></div>');
                        $(link).parents('li').addClass('selected');
                        $("ul#ui-ajax-tabs li").removeClass("loading");
                        History.pushState(null, 'Error 500 (Internal Server Error)', url)
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you give us your ajax code?

Comment: define how the page is called by ajax-request ..where do you include the response?

Comment: You test on Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox? Type Ctrl+Shift+J and look if show errors.

Comment: Does .html() remove script tags that are in the page that is being loaded in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web page is text. The browser you use happens to interpret it when you request it from your servers.

If you're doing an ajax request, the content will be on a variable as a string waiting for you to do something. It doesn't matter if it has scripts on it, it won't auto execute.

You would have to create a script element with that as innerText and append it to the DOM to have it executed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your remote js code is not executed when you call AJAX but you can return a js script as text and execute it on your page using the eval() function

Answer (score 0):

When you say you are "calling" a page via Ajax, do you mean you are requesting some HTML(dynamic or otherwise) from the server that happens to contain this JavaScript with it?

If so, that snippet should run, but not until you insert it into the DOM.

If you are using jQuery, the most typical way of getting HTML from a server and replacing the contents of a DOM element with it is the "load" method:

[jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason alert doesn't come up on ajax request is because the "document" has already executed the "ready" state.

Remove `$(document).ready()` from the js file (leave `alert()` on its on in there) and try loading  it via ajax. It should work.